# Reactflow and Next.js with app router - nodes and edges not rendered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-flow

I am trying the basic example using "reactflow": "^11.8.3" and "next": "13.4.19". I am using the app router of next.js. The nodes and edges are not rendered. The relevant html elements are not created.

Adding code for reference

Root
app/layout.js

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Next-Reactflow App router',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Flow page
app/flow/layout.js

```
import styles from './flow.module.css';
export default function FlowLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.flow}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

app/flow/page.js

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import ReactFlow from 'reactflow';
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';

const initialNodes = [
    { 
        id: '1', 
        position: { x: 100, y: 100 }, 
        data: { label: 'Node 1' } 
    },
    { 
        id: '2', 
        position: { x: 100, y: 200 }, 
        data: { label: 'Node 2' } 
    },
  ];
const initialEdges = [{ id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2' }];

export default function Flow() {
    return (
        <ReactFlow 
            nodes={initialNodes}
            edges={initialEdges}
        />
    )
}
```

app/flow/flow.module.css

```
.flow {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
```

[image: File structure]

I tried the same example with Next.js and ReactFlow same versions with pages router and the example creates nodes and edges.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is what I get in the browser. Nodes and edges are not created - no html tags for nodes and edges.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOR4Z.png

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your folder structure highlighting where the component you have shown?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I have added the folder structure. please check

Comment: The code you have given is working for me. How you are accessing the route?

Comment: I am using this url: http://localhost:3000/flow.

Comment: Same and it's working for me. What do you see when you go to the route? Anything on the browser console, or in your terminal?

Comment: I have added an image in the question at the end. Just a blank page with ReactFlow hyperlink at the bottom. Terminal shows nothing.

Comment: To replicate this problem:
1. Create the project using `npx create-next-app@latest`
select TypeScript - No, ESLint - Yes, Tailwind - No, src dir - Yes, App Router - Yes, customise default import alias - No
2. Install reactflow - npm i --save reactflow
3. Add the folder app/flow with the above code.
4. npm run dev and then go to localhost:3000/flow

Comment: Thanks @YoussoufOumar for checking and letting me know that this code is working. I updated my node version as you said its working and figured it out finally.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem got resolved when I upgraded my node and in turn npm version. It wasn't working with node 16.7. After upgrading to node 18.17.1 it worked.